# how can I use babel stand alone on internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, babeljs, polyfills

I would like to use babel stand alone on internet explorer 11.  I get the error

```
object doesn't support property or method 'assign'
```

I have seen the solution to use polyfills to fix it but I don't think it will work for me because I don't use node.js.  We use an apache server with a php back end and use fortrabbit to host so we can't even add node.js.

And I was wondering if there was anything I can do to fix this problem without using anything node.js related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because assign isn't a function on the object prototype in ie11.
There is a polyfill that will work in the browser you can use here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign